# Issue when trying to upload image in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I've been trying for more than 24h and didn't catch from where come the ERROR , trying to follow the Symfony DOC [How to Handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) step by step then when It hit the upload button in my Page form I get this ERROR :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\Page::setFile() must be an instance of Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\UploadedFile, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile given, called in C:\Users\THINK\Desktop\PHP-Symfony2---Build_a_CMS-master\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line 442 and defined
```

[image]

My Entity Page :

```
    <?php

namespace Custom\CMSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="pages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    private $temp;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
         $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (is_file($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            $this->path = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }



    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/image'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }


    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setCategory(\Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\Category 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }

        // you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
        // so that the entity is not persisted to the database
        // which the UploadedFile move() method does
        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension()
        );

        $this->setFile(null);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function storeFilenameForRemove()
    {
        $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        $file = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        if ($file) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }


}
```

the PageType who generate the form :

```
<?php

namespace Custom\CMSBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('file')
            ->add('content')
            ->add('category')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\Page'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'custom_cmsbundle_page';
    }
}
```

PageController :

```
<?php

namespace Custom\CMSBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\Page;
use Custom\CMSBundle\Form\PageType;

/**
 * Page controller.
 *
 */
class PageController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Page entities.
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('CustomCMSBundle:Page')->findAll();

        return $this->render('CustomCMSBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new Page entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Page();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity->upload();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cms_page_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('CustomCMSBundle:Page:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Page entity.
     *
     * @param Page $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Page $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PageType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('cms_page_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Page entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Page();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return $this->render('CustomCMSBundle:Page:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Page entity.
     *
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('CustomCMSBundle:Page')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Page entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('CustomCMSBundle:Page:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Page entity.
     *
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('CustomCMSBundle:Page')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Page entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('CustomCMSBundle:Page:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Page entity.
    *
    * @param Page $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Page $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PageType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('cms_page_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * Edits an existing Page entity.
     *
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('CustomCMSBundle:Page')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Page entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cms_page_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return $this->render('CustomCMSBundle:Page:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a Page entity.
     *
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('CustomCMSBundle:Page')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Page entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cms_page'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Page entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('cms_page_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is written in error message. If you didn't write "use some class" and "use" it in the code (in function signature eg.) - it is being searched in same (or global, just don't remember) namespace. Read: [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)
Page entity:
add

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
```